# WiFi troubles when power adapter is connected

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi

I'm having troubles with my WiFi router and my laptop at home. Communication between the two is crappy. So I made some test and also I tried different wifi channels and I discovered a weird thing:
If I ping my wifi router having the ac power adapter disconnected (running on battery) response is very fast (around 1 - 2 ms) and I have 0% packet loss.

If I connect the power adapter, the ping response gets very slow (even up to 13000 ms) and packet loss gets very high (around 73%).

Changing wifi channels doesn't help...
Is that an hardware problem or could it be some settings to check?
Anyone else is having similar issues?

I'm on archlinux and gnome shell 3.18. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hardware problem to me, especially considering the packet loss.
Something like this can happen when the power supply is shielded badly or there is a loose connection that causes small sparks. Ideally, you could test this with a replacement power supply. Before you buy a new power supply, you could try to wrap the power supply and the cable in aluminum foil. Do this only while the power supply is not connected to any socket and make sure you don't create any short!!! If that helps, you need to replace the power supply. Do not use the aluminum foil as a permanent solution, it is dangerous around electrical equipment!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bad ground isolation in your power adapter, or worse.

If the plug allows, try reversing it. You can do this with most plug types, but not all.  If that changes anything, that's most probably bad isolation inside the power adapter.  Just use it reversed, or change it.

Next thing, try a different power adapter (nowadays, they are essentially all compatible ones, but check the voltage to be sure).

If changing the power adapter does not help, you could have some sort of disturbance in your power network.  Try unplugging everything you can and try again, or just unplug one appliance at a time and see if that makes a difference.

As a last resort before putting the blame on your PC, try it somewhere else than your home.